# How to fix service control buttons are disabled for custom service

Tags: winapi, windows-services

I have a service that I start & it works fine (I verify it's running by looking at the EventLog messages it posts).  For some reason though, services.msc shows the stop button greyed out & I can't figure out why.

```
static SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE gServiceStatusHandle = NULL;

static DWORD WINAPI DaemonServiceHandler(DWORD control, DWORD eventType, LPVOID eventData, LPVOID context)
{
    HANDLE stopEvent = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(context);

    switch (control) {
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP:
        ReportServiceStatus(SERVICE_STOP_PENDING, 100, 3000);
        // notify main loop to stop
        return NO_ERROR;
    case SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE:
        return NO_ERROR;
    }
    return ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
}

void WINAPI DaemonMain(DWORD argc, LPWSTR *argv)
{
    gServiceStatusHandle = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(WIN_UTF16(gServiceName), DaemonServiceHandler, NULL);
    if (gServiceStatusHandle == NULL) {
        ReportService(SERVICE_STOPPED);
        return;
    }
    ReportService(SERVICE_RUNNING);
    // do main loop
    ReportService(SERVICE_STOPPED);
}

int tmain(int argc, tchar **argv)
{
    const SERVICE_TABLE_ENTRYW DispatchTable[] =
    {
        {(L"MyService", DaemonMain},
        {NULL, NULL}
    };
    if (!StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW(DispatchTable)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is sample pseudo-code of roughly what I'm doing - didn't test if it actually compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Bug in my ReportServiceStatus call.

I was setting dwControlsAccepted of the SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE to 0 always instead of enabling SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP when the current state to report wasn't SERVICE_START_PENDING.